# How to turn-on BLE using google play service apis

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I tried to turn on ble using location service of google plays service apis. First I connected with successfully.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build(); 
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

and inside onConnected(), I called setNeedBle(true):

```
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.setNeedBle(true);
        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        Log.d("TAG100","inside setNeedBle "+mLEScanner);
        settings = new             ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
        scanLeDevice(true);
}
```

but its not working. I am not even getting the popup.
Am I missing something?
Or is there any other location based services apis which can turn on ble.